# Activity second findViewById() call returns null after app restart

Tags: android

I have checked all the scenarios on StackOverFlow, but with no use.

Simply, I have implemented this [auto-restart after crash](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/how-to-auto-restart-an-android-application-after-a-crash-or-a-force-close-error-1a361677c0ce/) tutorial, it works perfectly.

I have different activities in my app, and if the app crashes and restarts, all of them restart normally. except one.

Here's the (onCreate) in **ConceptActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_concept);

    txtOurStory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOurStory);
    txtOurVision = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOurVision);

    MyConfig config = Web.getConfig(); //retrieve data from server

    txtOurStory.setText(config.ConceptStory);
    txtOurVision.setText(config.ConceptVision);       
}
```

and **activity_concept.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtOurStory"
                style="@style/concept_text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtOurVision"
                style="@style/concept_text" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code works perfectly on the first run, but if restarted from a crash, findviewbyid returns null .. I am using the exact steps/code in other activities and it's not happening. I tried almost all solutions found on stackoverflow wherever the scenario is similar, still nothing.

any ideas? thanks a lot in advance

**UPDATE**

Error from LogCat

```
05-24 16:02:20.356 22368-22368/com.company.appname E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 48024300 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 36MB until OOM"
05-24 16:02:20.366 22368-22368/com.company.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.company.appname, PID: 22368
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.appname/com.company.appname.MenuActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:428)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267)
                                                                          at com.company.appname.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:31)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:428) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267) 
                                                                          at com.company.appname.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:31) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288) 
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 48024300 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 36MB until OOM
                                                                          at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
                                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
                                                                          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3747)
                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3620)
                                                                          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:762)
                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:151)
                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
                                                                          at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:428) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2267) 
                                                                          at com.company.appname.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:31) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6288) 
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: put your stacktrace here

Comment: Post error here

Comment: in this xml layout there is no txtOurStory id, which probably causes the findviewbyid to return null

Comment: @peshkira I'm sorry I copied an old version of the code, this is not the issue. I edited my question

Comment: @user1313 this is out of memory exception which you need to analyze why your app is using so much memory and try to free them when you don't need it. analyze memory heap.

i guess there may be image in your layout at line no 18 used by `MenuActivity.java` which may be larger in resolution..

Comment: What happens on line 31 in your MenuActivity?

Comment: yeah I'm working on that, but after it crashes it auto-restarts (using tutorial in the link in my question) ... after the restart I debug the onCreate and findviewbyid now returns null ..

Comment: @peshkira, this is line 31 in MenuActivity  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);`

Comment: @user1313 it can not inflate layout because of low memory. try reducing memory usage and it should work as expected

Comment: @Prashant line 18 in MenuActivity is just a variable declaration `private ImageView burgerIcon;
`

Comment: @user1313 i mean line no 18 in your layout file. not in java class

Comment: @Prashant, Oh my mistake, yes it is an image view with a big resolution, let me try reduce it and test again, but is this related to findviewbyid returning null?

Comment: @Prashant, the image is 1020x1300 but file size is 13KB ... is 13KB big too big?

Comment: @user1313 can't guess about why it is returning null, but it doesn't matter how much your image is in size. android will generate bitmap pixel by pixel when you use it. so it will result in larger size in memory. as you said it is 1020 x 1300 which is large, use lower resolution if you don't really need large image

Comment: did you provide width and height of TextView?

Comment: @Prashant, I tried reducing image sizes, but the looked pixelated :( and the app still crashes, and upon restart activities work fine except concept activity ..

Comment: @hwd, width and height are specified yes. `        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue never happened since I following @Prashant's comment/suggestion:

> this is out of memory exception which you need to analyze why your app
>   is using so much memory and try to free them when you don't need it.
>   analyze memory heap. i guess there may be image in your layout at line
>   no 18 used by MenuActivity.java which may be larger in resolution..

I did go through my app and changed the Image Loading library which caused this exception, so the app never crashed since then therefore I couldn't really figure out if THIS was the solution to the problem. but it seems it was.

Answer (score 0):

`txtOurStory` id is not available in layout file.

Make sure all the ID's which you are using in Java must be available in layout file.

Comment: I'm sorry I copied an old version of the code, this is not the issue. I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

**Change this line id wrong**

```
txtOurStory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOurMission);
txtOurVision = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtOurVision);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I copied an old version of the code, this is not the issue. I edited my question